# Div Target for run CSS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I Target a div tag and run css. That div tag has no class or id I want to Target it's  tag and also that a tag has alt.
Basically that div is Auto generated. I want to run a script that will remove that tag. Or css tag display:none

Comment: Can you show what the html would look like when it is generated?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking. Could you post your code?

Comment: <div style='text-align: right;position: fixed;z-index:9999999;bottom: 0; width: 100%;cursor: pointer;line-height: 0;'><a title="Hosted on free web hosting 000webhost.com. Host your own website for FREE." target="_blank" href="https://www.000webhost.com/?utm_source=000webhostapp&utm_campaign=000_logo&utm_medium=website_eshayat&utm_content=footer_img"><img src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/23024110/20663010/9968df22-b55e-11e6-941d-edbc894c2b78.png"  alt="www.000webhost.com"></a></div>

Comment: this lines of codes are automated.
im thinking if i can target that div and a.alt "www.000webhost.com" and run css not to display then it should get removed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using jQuery.
Need more information, like where does this div exist.
But something very useful would be the $( "div" ).remove(); 
First we need to specify where the div exist is it a child or a sibling. 
Then easily use .remove()
please look at https://api.jquery.com/remove/

But more info regarding were the div exist is required.

Now regarding selecting the div according to the position it is in, that is called traversing.

Here is the link with Documentation on traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

After you select it then use .remove()

Comment: the problem im facing is that div has no class or id in it

Comment: 1st do you know JavaScript or just css

Comment: 2nd we need the parent that the div belongs to, is it an other div with a class, is it <main> it should be inside an other element

Comment: With CSS first is the parent .parentClass > div:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}

Comment: i'm kind of in the process of learing JS.

Comment: If the div has no id or class you need to write code based on its relationship to other elements, ex (to who's child is it)

Comment: i can understand js codes. 
and thats under a main tag

Comment: Ok CSS is fine, who is his parent, then is it the first div, is it the second div, according to the number set the .parentClass > div:nth-child(2) { display: none; }. Does the parent have a class?

Comment: its a 3rd div. and yeah parent has a class "wrapper"

Comment: .wrapper > div:nth-child(3) { display: none; }

Comment: Look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp and this  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp set the relationship and put display: none

Comment: a[href*="000webhost"]
{
 display:none;
}